# Create a way in .NET to determine X,Y locations on a PDF for printing

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, aspose

I have a PDF that is a template I will use to print onto special paper stock in a printer. I want to create a way to use the mouse to capture x,y locations when i click on certain areas of the pdf. The pdf template is based on an 8 1/2 x 11 piece of paper.

One of my ideas was to convert the page in the pdf to a jpg and load it into a picturebox using c# and a windows forms application. Then I can capture the x,y when i click the mouse but I'm not sure how that will translate to the pdf.

I'm open to opensource suggestions but I also have both the Aspose Words and Aspose PDF products. I'd also prefer a .NET solution.

Comment: A ticket with ID **PDFNET-36826** is already logged in our issue management system for conversion of mouse coordinates to Aspose.PDF for .NET standard unit, point. We have recorded your concerns and will let you know as soon as the ticket will be resolved. PS: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing a direct X/Y pixel co-ordinate then, you could store them as a % of the page.

So go down your jpeg idea, get the pixel X,Y of your location, then divide those by the Width,Height of the Jpeg to give you X%,Y%

When you come to do your printing, get the paper size and multiply that by your X%,Y% to get your offset within the print document

Answer (score 0):

In the end what worked for me was finding out that 1 inch = 72 points. So as far as the Aspose library was concerned that conversion factor worked for me. THEN I created a jpeg that was 1 pixel by 1 pixel and would stamp that on the PDF using the XIndent and the YIndent. This allowed me to stamp a pixel in the upper left corner of pdf and then using the width and height of the page and the conversion factor I was able to deduce the other 3 corners!

Comment: We are glad to know that shared information has helped you to achieve your requirements. Feel free to raise a query if you need any further assistance and we will be more than happy to assist you.

Comment: addendum: i discovered the best solution was to use C1Report Designer to lay out the textboxes using their GUI/designer. this gave me total control and as long as the paper size was accurate and i was printing to the correct tray it didnt care whether it was on a piece of paper or the wristband sheet.

Comment: alteratively you COULD use something like the C1 report designer or the SSRS designer in visual studio to do the layout and then consume the xml or rdl file. Its just xml and has all the x,y coordinates in it. Then its just a matter of converting from twips to points or whatever the units are. hope this helps someone else!